# Setting members of object using function fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a kind of multiplayer extension to a game I'm creating. After a XMLHttpRequest, a game ID is returned, i.e. the ID of a multiplayer session.

I'm using the following code, in which Multiplayer is a static class:

```
var Multiplayer = {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/m',
    gameID: -1,

    create:
    function() {
        $.get(this.baseURL, {'a':'c'}, function(text) {
            this.gameID = parseInt(text);
        });
    }
}
```

It fails, because it seems `this.gameID = parseInt(text)` cannot be used. When I change it to `Multiplayer.gameID = parseInt(text)`, it works like a charm.

It seems like `this.gameID` is undefined, while `Multiplayer.gameID` can both be written to and read from.

Is this correct and if so, why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have classes, and `this` does not behave as you expect coming from a C++ or Java background.  Try changing your create function to this:

```
function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get(this.baseURL, {'a':'c'}, function(text) {
        that.gameID = parseInt(text);
    });
}
```

The key points are that every function() is invoked with a particular `this` value, and it may not be the same value as the enclosing function's.

Comment: I see, I used `console.log(this)` and it did not return the Multiplyer object, but the JQuery AJAX class instead. Thanks for the solution.